# Paypal Payments Advanced issue in Magento

Tags: api, magento, shopping-cart, paypal

I use Paypal Payments Advanced for my Magento shopping cart. I found out a customer from Canada got credit card declined continuously. I talked to the customer directly and did the following test:

1. Go to Virtual Terminal in my Paypal Manager to just test authorization and it doesn't work either. Virtual Terminal's Single Transaction test gave error:
   Result Code: 12 Response Message: 
   Declined: 15005-This transaction cannot be processed.
2. I sent a $2 invoice in my Paypal account and that also doesn't work.
3. The customer then used the credit card from some other place and it works just fine. Then the customer also gave me another card and the test fail again.

My US customers are doing just fine. Only Canadian banks!

Can someone tell me what's wrong? My suspicion is I have to turn on "Enable Secure Token" in Paypal Manager > Service Settings > Set Up. I don't have SSL yet for my shopping cart website (as I think that's not needed due to Paypal Payments Advanced is just an iframe).

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is Sue from PayPal.  I'm not exactly sure what is going on here, but did you know that you have free technical support for PayPal Payments Advanced?   You can enter your question at www.paypal.com/mts.  Or if you login to your account at manager.paypal.com, then click Support in the top right corner, and you will find the phone support number.

Also, you should definitely set Secure Token to Yes, but I don't think that would be related to what you describe above.